# MATLAB: Plot variables in workspace without manually changing its subscript

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I have 3 different sets of data in my variable workspace with a subscript by its name for identification.

First Set in workspace:

```
lat1 = rand(10,1);
long1 = rand(10,1);
alt1 = rand(10,1);
time1 = rand(10,1);
```

Second Set in workspace:

```
lat2 = rand(10,1);
long2 = rand(10,1);
alt2 = rand(10,1);
time2 = rand(10,1);
```

Third Set in workspace:

```
lat3 = rand(10,1);
long3 = rand(10,1);
alt3 = rand(10,1);
time3 = rand(10,1);
```

Each time, manually, I enter into the code and change the subscript, such as from `plot(time1,lat1) TO plot(time2, lat2)`.  I want to plot all these data sets using a for loop (or another construct choice) without having to change the subscript each time for plotting.  Something similar to below or another way to achieve the selected output:

```
for k = 1:3
plot(time1(k), lat(k))
plot(time1(k), long(k))
plot(time1(k), alt(k))
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, so I don't fully understand what you want, but I think this might be helpful.

Can you just put them into an array and plot different columns in the array?

Something like:

```
lat = rand(10,3);
long = rand(10,3);
alt = rand(10,3);
time = rand(10,3);

for ii=1:3
    figure
    hold on
    plot(time(:,ii),long(:,ii),'o')
    plot(time(:,ii),alt(:,ii),'o')
    plot(time(:,ii),lat(:,ii),'o')
end
```

Then if you wanted to change one of the variables you just change the corresponding column. For example, if you wanted to change the equivalent of lat3, you'd just set

```
lat(:,3)=rand(10,1)
```